# Are these cracks in a brick wall due to subsidence?

Tags: brick, cracks

I've had my house about 5 years now, I did notice these cracks but nothing showed up in the report but now I'm starting to get quite worried about them. They've not gotten worse from what I can see and I can't see any cracks internally (Although, there's a cabinet right behind the cracks so I'm guessing I wouldn't be able to see them if there was). I am not sure if this is an cause for concern as there's no other cracks internally or externally that would show subsidence in the house.

If anyone else has any ideas I would be interested to hear them. There is actually a window above this door which has a small bit of plastic taken out of the bottom where the latch goes, now I'm starting to wonder if they took it out as it started to stick but in the past 5 years I've not actually experienced it getting worse myself.

does anyone know if this may be a structural problem? If anyone else has had similar or knows about subsidence cracks please let me know what the best steps are to get this investigated further? I live in the north east of England if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please note that this is a _Question_ and Answer site, not a general discussion forum. You'll note that you've not actually asked a question, so it's hard for us to provide an answer. Please [edit] this to ask an actual, specific question ("should I worry" is opinion based and will get closed, "How can I check for further movement" is very specific and will get you a good answer). As it stands, this may get closed for being too broad and needing more detail.

Comment: I've modified this to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably some subsidence, yes, but you don't know how old. As others have said, what you really want to know is whether things are still moving. I'd say go ahead and fix this but monitor for recurrence or other evidence that motion is continuing.

At over 100 years, I'd guess these are case-hardened bricks, which would mean the repair would have to be done with lime mortar rather than a modern concrete-based version. Not a problem, but you may need to special order or mail order it if you can't find a local store which has it in stock.  If you want to be sure, or want to do a historically accurate repair, there are labs which can test a sample of the mortar and tell you what it's actual composition was, and companies which can give you an exact color match; I just presumed and went with an off-the shelf mix.

(I'm in New England, not Merrie Olde.)

Comment: Thanks for this. Having a look around the wall there are actually some other bricks which have larger mortar lines on the other side of the door so I'm guessing it has had some in the past as they've not opened up in the last 5 years (At least). I'll patch it up and see what happens with this section as well. If it reoccurs, I have building insurance so I'm guessing the best thing to do would be to get in touch with them and they'll confirm.

Comment: I'd get the site evaluated and get a quote before deciding whether I wanted to make an insurance claim and give up my "no claims" discount or pay for it myself. The insurance company will want that evaluation anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just patch it up for now and keep an eye on it over the next few months and see what happens. I have had old photos from 5 years back and it looks identical but I guess we're probably talking millimetres here so I'd not be able to tell without something to measure against so at least patching it up will do that or maybe a good old ruler as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are methods of checking for movement, which involve securing bits of plastic across the crack to see if it moves, some have sliding scales others rely on breakage.

The age of the property is a relevant factor here as this may represent "old" movement which has now stabilised. The ground may also be a factor to check - is it drying out or getting wetter etc.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will have a look into these methods. The property is very old so it could be old movement. I think it was built around 1880 so I do imagine there has been some movement especially since we live in an area of England that has had a lot of coal mining in the past.